# How to write a function which calculates product of even elements in the list from n to m position in python?

Tags: python, list

This is what I have tried already, but it only shows me two values, I want to see all even values in that interval, is that possible?

```
eL = [8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
m = []
n = []

for x in eL:
    if x % 2 == 0 and x == eL[0]:
        m.append(x)

for x in eL:
    if x % 2 == 0 and x == eL[4]:
        n.append(x)

print(m, n)
```

For example,
For the list `[8, 2, 4, 5, 6,10]`

and  `n = 1` and `m = 3`
the result should be `2 · 4`

And for `n = 0`, `m = 3`
the result should be `8 · 2 · 4`

And for `n = 2`, `m = 4` it should be `4 · 6`.

Comment: Could you please add the expected output?

Comment: where do m and n come into play? The question and the snippet are not clear.

Comment: For example, for the list [8, 2, 4, 5, 6,10], for n = 1 and
m = 3 the result should be 2 · 4, for n = 0, m = 3 the result should be 8 · 2 · 4,
and for n = 2, m = 4 it should be 4 · 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
eL = [8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
m = 1
n = 3
result = []
for x in eL:
    if x % 2 == 0 and (eL.index(x) >= m and eL.index(x) <= n):
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

You can use `.index` and `>=, <=`

Or (thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089310/how-to-write-a-function-which-calculates-product-of-even-elements-in-the-list-fr/65089386#comment115072348_65089386) by Tal J. Levy)

```
eL = [8, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
m = 1
n = 3
result = []
for x in eL[m:n+1]:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

Just loop it around like this: `for x in eL[m:n+1]:`

Comment: For example, for the list [8, 2, 4, 5, 6], for n = 1 and
m = 3 the result should be 2 · 4, for n = 0, m = 3 the result should be 8 · 2 · 4,
and for n = 2, m = 4 it should be 4 · 6.

Comment: Oh, Okay thanks for the information. but please add that to the question.

Comment: @NiniNemsadze Updated, please check.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @ppwater, your code will not work if x appears in eL more then once.
Why not just run over the relevant slice?

`for x in eL[n:m+1]:

    # now just check parity.`

Moreover if only product is desired, you can already perform the multiplication, instead of appending the data to a new list.

Comment: Can you please show when it doesn't work? like the example eL list / and the expected output?

Comment: @ppwater just fix the `eL% 2` to `x % 2`

Answer (score 1):

Product of even numbers from n to m indexes:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>> n, m = 1, 4
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sublst = lst[n:m]
>>> evens = [i for i in sublst if i % 2 == 0]
>>> reduce(mul, evens, 1)
8
```